# How do I make a Sprite revolve around a point in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

In my Phaser 3 game I have an object which I want to revolve around a point (x,y) in a circle of a specific radius say 5 units. All the tutorials are in Phaser 2, so please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.html#.RotateAroundDistance). There is an example [here](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cactions%5Crotate%20around%20distance.js)

In case the link breaks in the future, the parameters are

```
RotateAroundDistance(point, x, y, angle, distance):
```

And an exmple use on a group of objects is below:

```
Phaser.Actions.RotateAroundDistance(group.getChildren(), { x: 400, y: 300 }, 0.02, 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to set the `anchor` of the sprite outside the actual sprite. The anchor is the pivot point or "handle" on the sprite, effectively an offset for the x,y position and angle etc. The further away you set the anchor, the bigger the radius will be.

And then add a tween to rotate the angle. So something like:

```
// setAnchor, x offset = 10 to the right of the sprite, y offset = center of sprite
mysprite.setAnchor(10.0, 0.5);

var tween = game.tweens.add({
  targets: mysprite,
  angle: 360.0,
  duration: 1500,
  repeat: 0
});
```

Comment: Does `anchor` exist in Phaser 3?

Comment: It does not.  The rough equivalent is `origin` but it is not an exact replacement.  Updated via .setOrigin()